# How to update internal values of a PreferenceActivity when SharedPreferences change

Tags: android, preferences, reset

I use a Preference in a PreferenceActivity to load default values: when this specific Preference is clicked, something like this happens:

```
private String mResetKeys = "key1,key2,key3";

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor prefs_editor = prefs.edit();
for (String current_pref : mResetKeys.split(",")) {
    prefs_editor.remove(current_pref);
}
prefs_editor.commit();
```

But afterwards, the Preferences whose corresponding SharedPreference was reset still show the old value - it seems to be cached in the Preference. Only when I leave the PreferenceActivity and reopen it, the Preferences show the new values.

How can I update the PreferenceActivity programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  This probably isn't the *most correct* fix but it worked for my purposes.  Right after I did the commits, I called the `Activity.recreate();` method.

The activity will restart (`onDestroy()`/`onCreate()`/etc) but for my purposes all I needed was a special handling on one preference.  I listened for a certain preference with an `OnPreferenceClickListener` and made an alert dialog box with a kind of warning message and an option to change their mind.  If they did want to change their mind, I did my commit of the new value to the preference activity and then called `recreate()` so that the checkbox preference would be updated.

However, I am also interested in a way to do this without recreating the activity...

Comment: Right, the SharedPreferences get written, but the PreferenceActivity and its hierarchy of PreferenceScreens don't get updated.  It took me hours just to figure out that this was the case... recreate()! Yes!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update preference value without reloading PreferenceActivity
from http://liquidlabs.ca/2011/08/25/update-preference-value-without-reloading-preferenceactivity/

Here is how to update default shared preference value of target element (in this case EditTextPreference)

```
public class YourCustomPreference extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

// some logic goes above, when you want to reset value and update EditTextPreference value
// For convenience, I am going to wrap two different task in different methods
private void resetPreferenceValue() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit(); // Get preference in editor mode
    prefEditor.putString("your_edit_text_pref_key", "DEFAULT-VALUE"); // set your default value here (could be empty as well)
    prefEditor.commit(); // finally save changes

    // Now we have updated shared preference value, but in activity it still hold the old value
    this.resetElementValue();
} 

private void resetElementValue() {
    // First get reference to edit-text view elements
    EditTextPreference myPrefText = (EditTextPreference) super.findPreference("your_edit_text_pref_key");

    // Now, manually update it's value to default/empty
    myPrefText.setText("DEFAULT-VALUE"); // Now, if you click on the item, you'll see the value you've just set here
}
}
```